# When creating custom component variants in MUI-5, how to choose the base variant for the custom one?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to have my custom `Divider` variant to be just like builtin `'middle'`, but thick and short. It seems like the default `'fullWidth'` variant is used as a base one and there is no answer in documentation, how to use another variant as a base.

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiDivider: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'thick-short' },
          style: {
            //This style got merged with 'fullWidth' one
            //but I would like to have 'middle'
            borderBottomWidth: '16px',
            width: '20%',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default values for props using `defaultProps` in theme:

```
MuiDivider: {
    defaultProps: {
         variant: 'thick-short'
    },
    // ...
}
```

See the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#default-props)

Comment: I don't need to change default variant, I need my custom variant based on non-default one

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/6c0dd98ea62c3711984f91e0cd3ff62ad04cd216/packages/mui-material/src/Divider/Divider.js#L78) there is no way to reference the styles of `middle` variant, or reuse it. If the variant of divider is `middle`, the styles specified here will overwrite the default variant styles, `fullwidth`. You have to create a new variant and include the styles of the `middle` variant and duplicate the code, or you could create a new divider component.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that place in code and already did my task the way you're describing. Yet, I've decided to post the question just in case I were missing something because libraries developers sometimes visit this question-answer website.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but I'm answering for those who have a similar problem.

This is what I do in such a case:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiDivider: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'thick-short' },
          style: {
            borderBottomWidth: '16px',
            width: '20%',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
})

// The style definitions in createTheme will override these style definitions.
theme.divider.["thick-short"] = {
  ...theme.divider.middle,
  // ... other style definitions or media quaries if necessary
}
```